# Even after setting TNS_ADMIN, Oracle uses the default tnsnames.ora

Tags: linux, oracle12c, tnsnames

In our LINUX box, due to some security reasons we need to test out a Database connectivity using an alternative tnsnames.ora file, instead of making changes directly in the default file under /network/admin. For this reason, after setting $ORACLE_HOME, we are also setting TNS_ADMIN, which points to a dummy tnsnames which we need to use. 
For example : export TNS_ADMIN=/psapps/admin/tnsnames.ora
However, even after setting this file, when tried to tnsping, Oracle still uses the default tnsnames.ora

Any suggestions in this matter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TNS_ADMIN should point onto a directory, not onto a particular file.

There can be other files in this directory, for example sqlnet.ora.

Comment: Thank you , after pointing TNS_ADMIN to the directory containing tnsnames.ora file. the issue was resolved.